# C# WPF Cancel ProgressBar from a different Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a UserControl with a big table that is displaying values using a lot of converters. I am trying to display a ProgressBar in a new Window with Indeterminate State that is closing automatically when the UserControl Loaded event is fired.

This is the Thread creation in the backcode of my UserControl :

```
Thread progressBarThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { 
    ProgressBarWindow progressBarWindow = new ProgressBarWindow();
    progressBarWindow.IsIndeterminate = true;
    progressBarWindow.LaunchProgressBarInBackground();
    progressBarWindow.ShowDialog();
}));

progressBarThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
progressBarThread.Start();

this.Loaded += (sender, e) => { Dispatcher.FromThread(progressBarThread).InvokeShutdown(); };
```

This code is "working", it is opening progressBarWindow but when I shutdown the thread using InvokeShutdown (the ugliest way to do it, i agree). The problem is that the DoWork from my backgroundWorker.

Here is the DoWork function :

```
private void BackgroundWorker_WaitUntilShouldStop(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do not access the form's BackgroundWorker reference directly.
    // Instead, use the reference provided by the sender parameter.
    BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    // Start the time-consuming operation.
    while (!bw.CancellationPending)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

I would like to call my function contained in ProgressBarWindow to stop the DoWork from runnning and close the ProgressBarWindow normaly using :

```
progressBar.StopProgressBarInBackground();
```

This method is calling `backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();`

This will result in backgroundWorker terminating and progressBarWindow closing automatically.

But I don't have access to progressBar that is inside the progressBarThread. I tried to pass my UserControl using :

```
progressBarThread.Start(this);
```

`this` being the main window.

When trying to pass a variable from the main thread, this error is thrown :

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code  Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Does someone have a nice and correct way to do it without using myThread.InvokeShutdown() ?

**Edit 1 :**

I found a solution to my problem using a volatile variable :

```
volatile bool _isLoaded;
void CreateAndStopProgressBarWhenIsLoaded()
{
    Thread progressBarThread= new Thread(new ThreadStart(    
    {
        Controls.ProgressBar.ProgressBar progressBar = new Controls.ProgressBar.ProgressBar();
        progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
        progressBar.LaunchProgressBarInBackground();

        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += (sender, e) => {
            if (_isLoaded)
                progressBar.StopProgressBarInBackground();
        };
        // Try to stop `progressBar` every 500 ms
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();

        progressBar.ShowDialog();

        // Will only be reached once progressBar.ShowDialog(); returns
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    }));
    progressBarThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    progressBarThread.Start();

    this.Loaded += (sender, e) => {
        _isLoaded = this.IsLoaded;
        progressBarThread.Join(); // Wait for progressBarThread to end
    };
}
```

Now the question is do you have a better solution ?

**Edit 2 :**

Here is my final solution thanks to @AlexSeleznyov :

```
    void CreateAndStopProgressBarWhenIsLoaded()
    {
        Controls.ProgressBar.ProgressBar pb = null;
        ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        Thread progressBarThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            Controls.ProgressBar.ProgressBar progressBar = new Controls.ProgressBar.ProgressBar();
            pb = progressBar;
            manualResetEvent.Set();
            progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
            progressBar.LaunchProgressBarInBackground();

            progressBar.ShowDialog();
        }));
        progressBarThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        progressBarThread.Start();

        this.Loaded += (sender, e) => {
            pb.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate {
                manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
                pb.StopProgressBarInBackground();
            });
            progressBarThread.Join();
        };
    }
```

Comment: can you perhaps simply make a progressbar in xaml, and bind the visibility to some property in your viewmodel, which you then set to collapsed once your view is loaded?

Comment: You need to switch back to UI thread when working with `ProgressBar` control. Use `CheckAccess` to determine wherever you need to do so.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov Unfortunatly I don't have access to my progressBar variable in the `Loaded` event.

Comment: @FlorianTalour you don't need that. UI thread is the same in your case so just use Windows's CheckAccess and if it is false, use Dispatcher.Invoke to switch to UI thread and update any UI control there.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov I did not understand what you said. I have two UI thread, one with my main window (with the usercontrol) that I am waiting for it's loaded event and one for the progress bar for it's animation to work. I want to close the second window (the progress bar) when the first one has loaded.

Comment: @FlorianTalour you might want to try the approach I suggested in the answer as comments doesn't allow for large code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this approach, to cache `ProgressBar` instance and then use it from another thread. `Dispatcher.Invoke` eradicates need for `CheckAccess` I've mentioned in comments.

```
void CreateAndStopProgressBarWhenIsLoaded()
{
    var pb = new Controls.ProgressBar.ProgressBar[1];

    Thread progressBarThread= new Thread(new ThreadStart(    
    {
            Controls.ProgressBar.ProgressBar progressBar = new Controls.ProgressBar.ProgressBar();
            pb[0] = progressBar;
            progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
            progressBar.LaunchProgressBarInBackground();

            progressBar.ShowDialog();
    }));
    progressBarThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    progressBarThread.Start();

    this.Loaded += (sender, e) => {
         pb[0].Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>pb[0].Close());
    };
```

}

Comment: Thanks you it worked. I replaced `var pb = new Controls.ProgressBar.ProgressBar[1];` with `Controls.ProgressBar.ProgressBar pb = null;` and it still works. Is it safe to assume that pb is initialized when Loaded is called ?

Comment: Yes, it works as you are setting value from within the lambda and do so only once. It won't work should you need to change the value from outside the lambda but that's completely another topic. As for `pb`  value - in most cases, yes, it will be initialized. For those cases when your big table's loading takes less time than progress bar instantiation I'd have added simple sync using `ManualResetEventSlim` and 'WaitOne'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) in ProgressBarWindow - it will be invoked when you cancel a backgroundWorker.

```
private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
                                                 RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        //close the window
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my backgroundWorker is never reaching this point until I call `backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();` to end the infinite loop of `Thread.Sleep(500);`